# Can I use Asynchronous Blur Validation with redux-form on a hidden input field?

Tags: redux-form

I have a [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) specific question.

I have a hidden input in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" {...field} />
```

And would like to perform some asynchronous validation by making a request to the server. What is the most elegant/appropriate way to achieve this? I've been looking into Asynchronous Blur Validation, which seems like the right thing except for the fact that a hidden input doesn't seem to be able to trigger a blur event.

**EDIT**

I managed to get what I wanted by hooking up the following middleware code to Redux:

```
  if (action.type === ActionTypes.MY_EVENT) {
    MyModule.asyncValidate({
      myField: store.getState().form.myForm.myField.value,
    }).catch((error) => {
      store.dispatch(stopAsyncValidation('myForm', error));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, asking how to do something when a hidden input blurs is like asking how to do something when your water is dry.

The concept of hidden inputs doesn't really exist in `redux-form`, as hidden inputs are based on the ye olde HTML way of submitting forms. A "hidden input" in `redux-form` is just a field that appears in the `fields` list (so it will be submitted), but that is not rendered to any input. I do this for primary keys, where my `fields` list is `['id', 'name', 'email']`, and I only render inputs for `name` and `email`, but all three get submitted.

I think what you want is for your async validation to fire when a rendered (non-hidden) field is blurred, and for all of the fields, even the ones that are not rendered, to be passed to the async validation function. With the example above, something like this would work:

```
reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm',
  fields: ['id', 'name', 'email'],
  asyncValidate: doServerSideAsyncValidation,
  asyncBlurFields: ['name', 'email'] // both rendered fields will trigger async validation
})
```

Comment: Thanks @erik-r. The validation is for checking whether a file has been successfully uploaded, so I wouldn't want to wait for another field to be touched before validating (especially because the upload is triggered by user interaction). I'll edit my question to show you something that I've managed to get working.

Comment: Oh and thanks for the tip about removing the DOM element!