# React / Redux Form passing props to children

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a view in my project where a user can retrieve a list of pages and can also create a new page. My code looks like this:

PARENT COMPONENT (PAGES)

```
class Pages extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="pages container">
        <div className="pages">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <CreateNewPage projectId={ this.props.params.id } />
            </li>
            <li>Map list of exisiting pages</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CHILD COMPONENT (CREATE NEW PAGE)

```
class CreateNewPage extends Component {
  handleFormSubmit( { pageName, projectId } ) {
    this.props.CreatePage( { pageName, projectId } );
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, fields: { pageName, projectId } } =  this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit( this.handleFormSubmit.bind( this ) ) } >
        <label>Create new page</label>
        <input { ...pageName } type="text" placeholder="Project name" />
        <input { ...projectId } type="hidden" value={ this.props.projectId } />
        <button type="submit">Create new page</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'createPage',
  fields: [ 'pageName', 'projectId' ]
}, null, actions )( CreateNewPage );
```

Pages receives an ID as a prop from React Router and I want to make that available to the Redux Form in my "Create New Page" component so I can associate the page with the project in my DB.

I am currently making the project ID available by passing it as a prop to the "Create New Page" component then storing it in a hidden input field.

This is my first Redux application so all I want to know am I doing this correctly? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than sending the project ID over in a hidden input, couldn't you simply pass it as an argument in your createPage function?

```
this.props.createPage(projectId, { pageName });
```

Where projectId could be this.props.projectId

Answer (score 3):

Joshua Slate's answer is correct. The `projectId` doesn't need to be a field at all.

On an educational side note... Hidden inputs don't make sense in `redux-form`. I'll quote my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078828/can-i-use-asynchronous-blur-validation-with-redux-form-on-a-hidden-input-field):

> The concept of hidden inputs doesn't really exist in redux-form, as
>   hidden inputs are based on the ye olde HTML way of submitting forms. A
>   "hidden input" in redux-form is just a field that appears in the
>   fields list (so it will be submitted), but that is not rendered to any
>   input. I do this for primary keys, where my fields list is `['id', 'name', 'email']`, and I only render inputs for name and email, but all
>   three get submitted.